# Computing Conditional probability

Tags: probability, statistics

I have two ordinary fair dice (one blue, one green). And the two random variables
$X=(S,p_x)$
and
$Y= (T,p_y)$ where $S=\{a,b\}$ and $T=\{c,d\}.$

The outcome
$a$ denotes that the blue dice showed $5$ or $6$, and outcome
$b$ denotes that the blue dice showed **1, 2, 3, or 4**.  Outcome
$c$ denote that the sum
of the faces is **10 or greater**, and outcome
$d$
denotes that the sum of faces is either 9 or less.

I am guessing that these two random variables are dependent variables? I'm not quite sure how to prove that.

I'm looking to compute $P(c\mid a)$ the conditional probability
"the probability that the sum will be **greater than 10**. If a is **5 or 6**"

listing the possible outcomes I get (6,4) (6,5) (6,6) (5,5) (5,6) so that means I have a 5/36th chance?

I also have the formula $p_z(x,y) / p_x(x)$ But I am not quite sure how to find $p_z(x,y)$

would 5/36 be $p_z(x,y)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, to compute conditional probabilities use the formula
$$P(c|a)=\frac{P(c\cap a)}{P(a)}$$

Your $5/36$ is actually the probability of $P(c\cap a)$ because the outcomes you listed are precisely the ones for which the sum is greater than or equal to $10$ $\textbf{and}$ the first one is $5$ or $6$. Since $P(a)$ is clearly $2/6=1/3$, we have
$$P(c|a)=\frac{P(c\cap a)}{P(a)}=\frac{5/36}{1/3}=5/12$$

The events $c$ and $a$ are independent if $P(c|a)=P(c)$ i.e. knowledge that $a$ occurred does not affect our knowledge of $c$ occurring. We've already computed $P(c|a)=5/12$. To compute $P(c)$, just write down all the outcomes for which $c$ occurs: $(4,6),(5,5),(5,6),(6,4),(6,5),(6,6)$. There are $6$ of them, so $P(c)=6/36=1/6\neq P(c|a)$. Therefore the events are dependent.

Comment: Ah okay, How do i prove that my variables are dependent?

Comment: @Aldrec I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You are given that the blue dice has a 5 or a 6. They each occur 1/2 of the time, thus
$$\frac{1}{2} \cdot P(sum>10|blue=5)+\frac{1}{2} \cdot P(sum>10|blue=6)$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{2}{6}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{3}{6}=\frac{5}{12}$$

Comment: wheres does the 1/2 come from?

Comment: Okay, but why do we have 2/6? they are both equally likely to occur no?

Comment: @V.Chen I think you misread the question. $c$ is the event that the sum is $10$ or greater, not just greater. So on the second line, $1/6$ should be $2/6$, and the $2/6$ should be $3/6$. This will give you an answer of $5/12$